# Need help understanding tightest lower bound ( BigOmega ) of n!

Tags: complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, complexity-classes

I am currently learning complexity theory and wasn't able to find a tightest lower bound to **BigOmega(n!)**, I am quite certain it isn't **n^n** and so wasn't able to reach to a tightest lower bound, can **log(n)^n** be the one, of course lose lower bounds are possible, but can you please help me understand the tightest lower bound of **n!**?

Comment: Why you are not trying to use Stirling approximation formula?

Comment: The tight lower bound is $n! = \Omega(n!)$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I don't feel like that's particularly helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are indeed correct that it isn't $n^n$ (though this is good enough for most purposes). As OmG mentioned in the comments, there is a standard approximation formula called "[Stirling's approximation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)" which gives the following asymptotic bound:

$$n!=\Theta\Big(\sqrt{n}\frac{n^n}{e^n}\Big)$$

Comment: Big O is an upper bound. OP was looking for a lower bound.

Comment: You are right. I will change it to theta to be more precise.

Comment: No I was not aware of Stirling's formula, thanks.